# SessionStorage doesn't worlk when i refresh a page

Tags: javascript, html

I want to resize the font-size of body html with a click on a button
First, When i click on my 2 buttons to resize the font-size it works perfectely: the first one make my text body normal size et the second one make it bigger, 1.5em ... but when i refresh the page it cancels. 
Can some one help me ? thanks !

```js
function functionSize() {
 var smallSize = document.getElementById("smallSize"); 
 var bigSize = document.getElementById("bigSize"); 
 smallSize.onclick= function() {
  sessionStorage.setItem("size","1em")
  document.body.style.fontSize=sessionStorage.getItem("size")
 } 
 bigSize.onclick = function(){
  sessionStorage.removeItem("size");
  sessionStorage.setItem("bigSize","1.5em")
  document.body.style.fontSize=sessionStorage.getItem("bigSize")
 }
}

functionSize()
```

```html
<div class="button-resize">
   <button class="small-size" id="smallSize">A</button>
   <button class="big-size" id="bigSize">A</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Your only loading the fontsize from sessionStorage when you click a button.  You need to load on page load too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call init after loading page:

```
function initFunctionSize() {
  var smallSize = document.getElementById("smallSize");
  var bigSize = document.getElementById("bigSize");

  smallSize.onclick = function () {
    setSize("1em");
  }
  bigSize.onclick = function () {
    setSize("1.5rem");
  }
  // init:
  if (sessionStorage.getItem("size")) {
    document.body.style.fontSize = sessionStorage.getItem("size");
  }
}

function setSize(size) {
  sessionStorage.setItem("size", size);
  document.body.style.fontSize = size;
}

initFunctionSize();
```

Comment: It works! thanks ! just correct (size) instead of (s) on function setSize()